# opencascade and opencascade74 conlict

Tags: manjaro

My requirements are to use FreeCAD, KiCAD and atom. The conflict between opencascade and opencascade74 are preventing me.

What can i do to fix this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If FreeCAD is already installed on your system (in this case manjaro linux), upon installing atom and KiCAD, use these terminal commands:

```
sudo pacman -S atom --ignore freecad

sudo pacman -S kicad --ignore freecad
```

These both worked which was a great outcome.